# Kamailio-Asterisk - route "FROMASTERISK" not found

Tags: sip, asterisk, kamailio

I'm trying to implement Kamailio 4.1 with Asterisk 12.1.0 regarging this tutorial:

```
http://kb.asipto.com/asterisk:realtime:kamailio-4.0.x-asterisk-11.3.0-astdb
```

And when I try to compile kamaili.cfg, I still got this error:

```
Apr 19 16:59:31 debian /usr/local/sbin/kamailio[5751]: ERROR: <core> [route.c:1137]: fix_actions(): route "FROMASTERISK" not found at /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg:780
```

I have loaded all modules like in tutorial.

I tried to find some solve this issue, but with no result.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error mean in your kamailio.cfg file not found section with route "FROMASTERISK"

Also note, that your kamailio config file is /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg

You have add section or remove route.